# string operation on pandas df

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas

pandas df with 11 columns need to modify first 3 columns using regex and add a new column with this modified column and us this for downstream concatenation, something like this I need to keep the element as is of these columns and make it a unique string

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 ...column 11
```

need to do this new_col = column1:column2-column3(column4)

and  make this new column,

```
column1 column2 column3 newcol column4 ...column 11
```

I could do this using simple python one line, not sure what is the syntax for pandas

```
l = cols[0] + ":" + cols[1] + "-" + cols[2] + "(" + cols[5] + ")"
```

Comment: Your example code will work fine if `cols[0]`, `cols[1]`, `cols[2]` and `cols[5]` are strings. If not, you need to convert them to strings before combining them. In standard python code you would do this with `str(cols[0])`. With pandas columns, you can do this with `cols[0].astype(str)`.

Comment: Agree, but i would have still not known how to add a new column to existing df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an answer that was recently deleted, this works fine:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'chrom': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    'start': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
    'end': ['g', 'h', 'i'], 
    'strand': ['j', 'k', 'l']}
)
df1['unique_col'] = df1.chrom + ':' + df1.start + '-' + df1.end + '(' + df1.strand + ')'
```

It sounds like your original dataframe may not contain strings. If it contains numbers, you need something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'chrom': [1.0, 2.0], 
    'start': [3.0, 4.0], 
    'end': [5.0, 6.0], 
    'strand': [7.0, 8.0]}
)
df1['unique_col'] = (
    df1.chrom.astype(str) + ':' 
    + df1.start.astype(str) + '-' + df1.end.astype(str)
    + '(' + df1.strand.astype(str) + ')'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do it with the same syntax you posted as long as all of the columns contain strings.

You can also use the [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat) method.

```
df['new_col'] = cols[0].str.cat(':' + cols[1] + '-' + cols[2] + '(' + cols[5]+ ')')
```

Comment: `df1['unique_col'] = df1['chrom'].str.cat(':' + df1['start'] + '-' + df1['end'] + '(' + df1['strand'] + ')')` gives me AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @sbradbio as I said "as long as all of the columns contain strings", if not you will need to cast the as strings as piRsquared did with `.astype(str)`

Comment: gotcha! need some more coffee missed the string part thanks.

Answer (score 2):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(a, (5, 10))).add_prefix('col ')

print(df)

  col 0 col 1 col 2 col 3 col 4 col 5 col 6 col 7 col 8 col 9
0     Q     L     C     K     P     X     N     L     N     T
1     I     X     A     W     Y     M     W     A     C     A
2     U     Z     H     T     N     S     M     E     D     T
3     N     W     H     X     N     U     F     D     X     F
4     Z     L     Y     H     M     G     E     H     W     S
```

Construct a custom `format` function

```
f = lambda row: '{col 1}:{col 2}-{col 3}({col 4})'.format(**row)
```

And apply to `df`

```
df.astype(str).apply(f, 1)

0    L:C-K(P)
1    W:A-C(A)
2    W:H-X(N)
3    E:H-W(S)
4    Y:E-P(N)
dtype: object
```

Add a new column with `assign`

```
df.assign(New=df.astype(str).apply(f, 1))
# assign in place with
# df['New'] = df.astype(str).apply(f, 1)

  col 0 col 1 col 2 col 3 col 4 col 5 col 6 col 7 col 8 col 9       New
0     Q     L     C     K     P     X     N     L     N     T  L:C-K(P)
1     I     X     A     W     Y     M     W     A     C     A  X:A-W(Y)
2     U     Z     H     T     N     S     M     E     D     T  Z:H-T(N)
3     N     W     H     X     N     U     F     D     X     F  W:H-X(N)
4     Z     L     Y     H     M     G     E     H     W     S  L:Y-H(M)
```

Or you can wrap this up into another function that operates on `pd.Series`.  This requires that you pass the columns in the correct order.

```
def u(a, b, c, d):
    return a + ':' + b + '-' + c + '(' + d + ')'

df.assign(New=u(df['col 1'], df['col 2'], df['col 3'], df['col 4']))
# assign in place with
# df['New'] = u(df['col 1'], df['col 2'], df['col 3'], df['col 4'])

  col 0 col 1 col 2 col 3 col 4 col 5 col 6 col 7 col 8 col 9       New
0     Q     L     C     K     P     X     N     L     N     T  L:C-K(P)
1     I     X     A     W     Y     M     W     A     C     A  X:A-W(Y)
2     U     Z     H     T     N     S     M     E     D     T  Z:H-T(N)
3     N     W     H     X     N     U     F     D     X     F  W:H-X(N)
4     Z     L     Y     H     M     G     E     H     W     S  L:Y-H(M)
```

Comment: It's not clear what should be in `a` in the second line of the first code block.

Comment: @piRSquared worked like charm many thanks!!!! could you please explain what you just did in the second block of code (lambda) and assign?

Comment: I use `assign` because it creates a copy of the dataframe and I typically don't want to clobber your dataframe by writing over it.  So I use `assign`.  However, very ofter, you see answers assign to a new column in the same dataframe.  That's perfectly fine.  Just not how I usually do it.

Comment: In the second block of code... honestly, its the same as what @Grr did, except I wrapped it in a function that is more readable.  By operating on the series as a whole, we avoid the inherent loop executed by `apply`.